# Could not locate '\efi\boot\bootx64.efi while installing windows 8.1 for dual-boot

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, multi-boot, uefi, ubuntu-14.04

I have a single-boot Ubuntu 14.04 installed on my system. Gparted shows the disk partitions like this:

[image]
At the moment, I want to do a clean install of Windows 8.1 so that I can dual-boot later (with Ubuntu 14.04). I created a bootable usb using [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/), selecting the "GPT partition scheme for UEFI" and NTFS options. To check, whether my machine was in UEFI mode, I used this command:

```
~$ df -h --local | grep /boot
/dev/sda2       237M  108M  117M  49% /boot
/dev/sda1       511M  3.4M  508M   1% /boot/efi
```

Seeing the above, I am assuming my machine supports UEFI. Also, in the BIOS settings, SecureBoot seems to be off, and Legacy Support Enabled:

[image]

The issue I am facing is that when I try to boot, I get the error:

```
[FAIL] Could not locate '\efi\boot\bootx64.efi': [14] not found
```

Here's a snapshot:
[image]

Could anyone please help with identifying the reason why this error is occurring? If I disable "Legacy Support", would it resolve this? I read up on the differences between UEFI and BIOS, and the function of Legacy Support, but I am kinda new to dual-booting so don't want to mess up. Would be glad of any help. Thanks!

Comment: Well it seems like you didn't make Rufus copy the content of the Windows ISO to the USB drive.

Comment: Rufus is a WIndows program. How did you use it in Ubuntu?

Comment: Disable legacy support.............Why is it enabled if you have an EFI partition?  There is also no reason to disable Secure Boot either...

Comment: Also, although your UEFI apparently has included an NTFS driver, you may still want to stick with the standard and use FAT32 instead, just in case it has a bad NTFS implementation as well.

Comment: Along with my mates said, you need to make sure that you burned a Windows 8.1 x64 ISO, and not x32 ISO, because the message indicates that the system couldn't find a bootx64.efi, which comes only with Windows x64 ISO.

Comment: @TomYan Thanks for the answer. I think I did add the iso file, but I'll check again. Also, I used NTFS because Rufus wouldn't make a bootable usb out of an iso > 4gb. What do you think I could do in that case?

Comment: @Zacharee1 I used it on a different machine.

Comment: @Ramhound I haven't touched the settings before, this is how I found them when I was checking my BIOS settings.

Comment: @QPTR ah, that explains it. But the Windows 10 ISO isn't greater than 4GB, is it?

Comment: @iSR5 will double-check, and make a boot-usb again. As far as I remember, it was an x64 iso.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I think the version appearing in 2017-18 or so may be above 4GB, given the current growth rate.

Comment: @PaulStelian Doubt it.

Comment: @PaulStelian I think they're going to do their best to keep it under 4GB. I've downloaded Apple ISOs and those things are huge (up to 8GB sometimes).

Comment: @Zacharee1 they are large due to many resources (I have seen many wallpapers that are so hi-res my Linux laptop can't render them properly). Windows has no such stuff/fluff/... Also, Windows' compression (the .esd format introduced with Windows 8.1) is way better than the dmg compression offered by Apple, which is rather similar to wim.

Comment: @PaulStelian exactly. I think Windows also wouldn't want to be more than 4GB because FAT32 is kind of "its format," if you get what I mean.

Comment: @Zacharee1 FAT32 is limited to 2GB, and so is ISO9660, and this barrier is broken already. Windows uses UDF format for sticks and NTFS for USB drives and the system reserved partition (FAT32 has not been used as Windows-native since the Windows 98 times?)

Comment: @PaulStelian I thought FAT32 was 4GB, and only 4GB files. I thought partitions themselves could be larger.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Well, for some reason I got limited to 2GB in my attempts. I would try to make a FAT32 disk image (which is large enough, say, 10GB) and write a file and see where it stops [perhaps it was Windows' implementation that was faulty and gave errors?]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42023/discussion-between-paul-stelian-and-zacharee1).

Comment: It works. I downloaded the iso again, turned off legacy, and created a fat32 bootable usb using rufus. There were other errors but the booting works.